# Firebase authentication with email/password

Tags: json, vb.net, authentication, firebase

I have added these 2 packages to my project:
https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet and
https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet

I am trying to access JSON data on Firebase from VB.NET, using API key and email/password for authentication. My code:

```
Async Sub AccessTheWebAsync()

    Dim authProvider = New FirebaseAuthProvider(New FirebaseConfig("myAPIkey"))

    Dim auth = authProvider.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync("myemail", "myPW").Result

    Dim firebase = New FirebaseClient("myFireBaseURL")

    Dim venues = Await firebase.Child("venues").OrderByKey().WithAuth(auth.FirebaseToken).OnceAsync(Of Venue)()

    'more code

end sub
```

Getting this error on "auth.FirebaseToken":
"Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Func(Of String)'"

Also tried this method (Google authentication):

```
Async Sub AccessTheWebAsync()

    Dim result = Await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets() With {.ClientId = myclientID, .ClientSecret = myclientsecret}, {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase"}, "user", CancellationToken.None)

    FetchFirebaseData(result.Token.AccessToken, FirebaseAuthType.Google)

End Sub

Private Async Sub FetchFirebaseData(accessToken As String, authType As FirebaseAuthType)

    Dim auth = New FirebaseAuthProvider(New FirebaseConfig(myFirebaseAppKey))

    'error on this line:
    Dim data = Await auth.SignInWithOAuthAsync(authType, accessToken)

    'more code to do something with the data

End Sub
```

The error message is: "message": "Cannot parse Google user profile response as JSON: {\"error\":{\"code\":403,\"message\":\"Insufficient Permission\",\"errors\":[{\"reason\":\"insufficientPermissions\",\"domain\":\"global\",\"message\":\"Insufficient Permission\"}]}}"

Ultimately, I want to be able to access the "data" (JSON), and also the "rules" (JSON) for my Firebase project. This is so I can create a very basic front-end that I can run on my local machine.

Comment: It expects a `Func(Of String)`, that is, a delegate pointing to a function that returns a string. I don't know how Firebase works, but you could try something like this: `.WithAuth(DirectCast(Function() auth.FirebaseToken, Func(Of String))).OnceAsync(Of Venue)()`.

Comment: Well that got rid of the error, but it's still not working 100%. I have veered off into a different direction though. Instead of logging into the API programmatically, I am instead using the "import JSON" feature for "data" on Firebase, and constructing my JSON by other means before uploading it.

Comment: That doesn't tell me much as I know nothing about Firebase :), so I'm afraid that was all I could do. I don't even know if it's the correct thing to do, I mean, the use of `Func(Of String)` is correct, but I don't know if that function also needs to do some other stuff than just return a string. Best I can say is: Good luck!

Comment: Cheers mate, thanks for your input.

Comment: Okay I can confirm that that's the correct way of doing it, so I'm going to post that as an answer. I found in Firebase's source code that an internal (aka `Friend` in VB) extension called `WithAuth()` (it has same name as the original function) uses the same technique that I did: https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet/blob/master/src/Firebase/Query/QueryExtensions.cs

Comment: From C# `node.WithAuth(() => token);` translates to `node.WithAuth(Function() token)` in VB.NET.

Comment: Since you've actually asked two questions at the same time, your second one can now be asked as a separate question as it has nothing to do with this any longer. :)

Comment: I've nominated your newest question to be reopened, however 3-5 others need to vote as well. Personally, even if it might be against Stack Overflow's guidelines, if you can delete that one and ask a new one I think that would be better.

Comment: (Sorry for the many comments, just want to be sure you see this) I suggest this because your newer question might not get reopened at all if you're unlucky... If you can't delete it and are uncertain of what to do, go to the chat or [**Stack Overflow Meta**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and ask for advice there.

Comment: I actually did make the 2nd one a new question, but they marked it as a duplicate and closed it. But anyway, like I said I am not accessing the API programatically any more, but instead using the "import JSON" feature on Firebase, after constructing my JSON. So I don't require any more help with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WithAuth()` method expects a `Func(Of String)` rather than a normal `String`.

A `Func(Of String)` is a delegate method pointing to a function that returns a string, so you can just have it return `auth.FirebaseToken` and it should work:

```
Dim venues = Await firebase.Child("venues").OrderByKey().WithAuth(DirectCast(Function() auth.FirebaseToken, Func(Of String))).OnceAsync(Of Venue)()
```