# Firebase API authentication

Tags: json, vb.net, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I posted a question yesterday: [Firebase authentication with email/password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42589885/firebase-authentication-with-email-password) Got no responses so I am trying a different approach: using Google authentication rather than email. Still having problems. My code:

```
Async Sub AccessTheWebAsync()

    Dim result = Await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets() With {.ClientId = myclientID, .ClientSecret = myclientsecret}, {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase"}, "user", CancellationToken.None)

    FetchFirebaseData(result.Token.AccessToken, FirebaseAuthType.Google)

End Sub

Private Async Sub FetchFirebaseData(accessToken As String, authType As FirebaseAuthType)

    Dim auth = New FirebaseAuthProvider(New FirebaseConfig(myFirebaseAppKey))

    'error on this line:
    Dim data = Await auth.SignInWithOAuthAsync(authType, accessToken)

    'more code to do something with the data

End Sub
```

The error message is:

> "message": "Cannot parse Google user profile response as JSON: {\"error\":{\"code\":403,\"message\":\"Insufficient Permission\",\"errors\":[{\"reason\":\"insufficientPermissions\",\"domain\":\"global\",\"message\":\"Insufficient Permission\"}]}}"

Ultimately, I want to be able to access the "data" (JSON), and also the "rules" (JSON) for my Firebase project. This is so I can create a very basic front-end that I can run on my local machine.

Comment: Instead of opening a new question, update your existing question with the new information.

Comment: Done. Can we leave this page open though? Those who looked at my other page before the edit, probably won't go back to it.